# Php getting all combinations for a n dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array of route elements (point1, point2, ...) to provide to a map engine.
I don't know how many points I have. Each point is an array of possible addresses.
I need to perform a check for every combination possible of these points, but only one successful check is required.

My array looks like something akin to:

```
$point[0] = array($address1, $address2, $adress3);
$point[1] = array($address1, $address2);
$point[2] = array($address1, $address2, $adress3, $adress4);
$point[n] = ...
```

I want to perform a test for combination: `$point[0][0] - $point[1][0] - $point[2][0], $point[0][1] - $point[1][0] - $point[2][0]`, and so on ! :)
The first successful test (route found) should end the function.

I'm trying to do something with recursion but have spent many hours on this without success.

Comment: So you have list of routes, each node is an address. What are you _checking_? Do you want to know if a set of address nodes is a route?

Comment: Longest match or shortest match or first match wins?

Comment: I have a first operation converting adresses string to adresses objects with latidute - longitude attributes. This first passage returns several possible addresses objects for each addresses strings.
I need to check every addresses objects combinaisons until the map engine finds a valid route.

Comment: First match wins ! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I got you right, you want to have a ["cartesian product"](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php).

This is an example function for it:
It first checks, if there are any subvalues in one of the subarrays and then it creates an array with all possible arraycombinations and returns it.

```
<?php
function array_cartesian_product($arrays)
{
    $result = array();
    $arrays = array_values($arrays);
    $sizeIn = sizeof($arrays);
    $size = $sizeIn > 0 ? 1 : 0;
    foreach ($arrays as $array)
        $size = $size * sizeof($array);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $size; $i ++)
    {
        $result[$i] = array();
        for ($j = 0; $j < $sizeIn; $j ++)
            array_push($result[$i], current($arrays[$j]));
        for ($j = ($sizeIn -1); $j >= 0; $j --)
        {
            if (next($arrays[$j]))
                break;
            elseif (isset ($arrays[$j]))
                reset($arrays[$j]);
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
?>
```

Comment: Wow thank you ! I was looking for something like that !